# flutter textfield number and auto clear

Tags: flutter

1. Why my textfield input type number is hard to type number, must type dot or commas then can type number
2. why after I move to next textfield, the first textfield auto clear?

but in web is normal, just on phone

[image]

this my code

```
final TFNik = TextEditingController();
    final TFPassword = TextEditingController();

Padding(
                  //padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:15.0,right: 15.0,top:0,bottom: 0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: TFNik,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                      WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                    ],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'NIK',
                        hintText: 'Enter valid NIK'),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 15, bottom: 0),
                  //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: TFPassword,
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Password',
                        hintText: 'Enter secure password'),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly is @Deprecated('Use FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow instead. ' 'This feature was deprecated after v1.20.0-1.0.pre.') from flutter documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you

declare TextEditingController

```
late TextEditingController username;
late TextEditingController password;
```

Declare controller for initState and dispose state

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    username = TextEditingController();
    password = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    username.dispose();
        password.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Declare Widget

```
 Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: TextField(
            controller: username,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'NIK',
                hintText: 'Enter valid NIK'),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 15, bottom: 0),
          //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
          child: TextField(
            controller: password,
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Password',
                hintText: 'Enter secure password'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Your result screen -> [image]